# Replacing three dots between square brackets JS

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm having a trouble with blog posts excerpt..

I'm using Wordpress as headless CMS and it returns me post excerpt in specific format.
It looks like `<p>some text here [...]</p>` and I'm trying to write one regular expression that will get rid of paragraphs and those brackets with dots in between.

I ended up with something like

`excerpt.replace(/<p>|<\/p>/g, '')` and it works with paragraphs but I can't find any solution to get rid of those three dots in one regular expression..

Is that possible at all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Comment: @adiga the problem wasn't with html tags but with the dots :P

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achive. Do you want to remove p tgas with those ellipsisi inside, or only th eellipssi itsel from p tags?

Comment: Don't forget to accept (tick check-mark next to the answer) your own answer (possible after a wait-period of 48 hours), so that your question stops showing up as unanswered in the searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I didn't notice one thing xD

Wordpress returns `[…]` instead of `[...]`..

Now everything works perfectly with something like

`const parsedExcerpt = excerpt.replace(/<p>|<\/p>|\r?\n|\r|\[…]/g, '');`